# Questions about MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

1 - Is MagicalRecord compatible with ARC?

2 - For this code

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *) MR_context NS_RETURNS_RETAINED
```

`NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` indicates that the `NSManagedObjectContext` created by above method will be retained so how one will make sure about its removal from memory once done?

3 - Even using `@autoreleasepool` block inside for loop doing an update on `NSManagedobject` entities fetched using

```
+ (NSArray *) MR_findAllWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)searchTerm inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
```

and subsequently calling

```
[context save:nil];
[context reset];
```

does not free up memory and it goes on increasing. Why it is so that calling `reset` on `NSManagedObjectContext` does not make the fetched entities invalid ? These entities do have relationships too. `context` is of type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to reply to your questions.

1- Yes. Magical record is ARC compatible. I've added the latest source code in a test project and I verified that no `release` call are there. In addition, `weak` qualifiers are used.

2 - No worry about it. Under ARC, memory will be managed for you. You can find a good explanation at [Migrating your code to Objective-C ARC](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/migrating-your-code-to-objective-c-arc/). See also section *3.2.2* of [Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

3 - It depends on your code. Doing a `reset` it will clean the specific context so memory footprint would be smaller. Anyway, here you should add some details.

I don't know Magical Record in deep but even if is a good lib (I think Saul Mora did a good work) I think you could just stay with plain Core data since it could be harder to find errors.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question 3, the reason you are not seeing freed up memory allocations in code such as:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    /// working stuff up here
    [context reset];
}
```

is basically because you don't have control of that memory. Core Data (the NSManagedObjectContext you've got) will cache objects for you. It also caches object data in the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator in memory as well. Generally, you should release the entire context once you're done with it to see some (even a small) memory usage drop. Don't worry about creating many contexts, they are lightweight and meant to be created all over the place like that.